# Hide or Disable MVC3 ActionLinks depending on cell value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.actionlink

MVC3 has created the following table for me

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
    </td>
     <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserCommentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserCommentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserCommentID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

I am sure everyone has seen this sort of thing a million times before.

Does anyone know if there is any way of hiding or disabling the Actionlinks depending on the item.Author.

(I only want an author be able to Edit or Delete his own comments)

I am thinking that the answer might lie with jQuery but I will be very happy with any solution at all.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
@if(item.Author == loggedInUserIdOrSomethingYouWantToCompareTo) {
    <text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserCommentID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserCommentID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserCommentID })
    </text>
}
```

obviously you should still check on the controller side to make sure the user has the permissions (it would be easy to "fake" these URLs).

Comment: Thanks Marek. Your solution works perfectly. I thought it would be a lot harder. You have saved me a lot time. Thanks also for your suggestion to check controller side, I would not have thought of that on my own.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marek's comments -  please check the current user when they post/get your edit page as well to make sure they have permissions to this. I could easily forge a link to access something I should have access to or even change any hidden form values you have to tamper with the model when editing something.